# How to decrease widget building cost?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a calendar with flutter. A part of this app is a screen that shows general look of all months in each year. So I have a page view that contains a grid view in it. The problem is because there is 12 calendar widgets in each page, app gets laggy and it doesn't look good at all.

So I'm looking for a way to reduce cost of building the calendar widget.

I'm using this calendar code: https://github.com/dan-iel-lee/calendar_widget

I'm also tried building GridView with builder constructor but it doesn't help. Also I'm tried to set PageView physics to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` but it doesn't help too much.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far so we can help you with that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?